# Why apply() here takes only one argument instead of two?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the book Javascript: The Good Parts. And I'm confused by the following code.

```
Function.method('curry', function (  ) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        args = slice.apply(arguments),
        that = this;
    return function (  ) {
        return that.apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)));
    };
});
```

Where is the `null` in `slice.apply(arguments)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arguments` is being passed as the context (`this`), not the function's arguments.

It's equivalent to `arguments.slice()`, except that `arguments.slice()` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

That's the equivalent of calling `slice()` on an array with no arguments - i.e. it returns an array with all the elements of the original array. In this case, 'arguments' is not a true array, so calling Array.prototype.slice on it in effect turns it into one.

Answer (score 1):

Two different functions are being invoked.
In the first case

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
args = slice.apply(arguments),
```

for great explanation refer to

http://blog.sebarmeli.com/2010/11/12/understanding-array-prototype-slice-applyarguments/

apply method of `Array.prototype.slice,` is being invoked, which will convert the arguments passed to the function into an array.

In the second function apply method of function is being called. The usage and details of this function is well defined here
http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/apply.html